# coalesce vs. concat functions with NULL values

Tags: sql-server, null, concatenation, coalesce

This is my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf5LW.png)
in my table i should use

```
SELECT
Title+' '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName+' '+LastName as FullName
from employees
Where BusinessEntityID IN (1,2,4)
```

But as a result i get only the middle row because that is the only one that does not contain NULL value.
The `concat()` works fine but i was wondering if there is a solution also with `coalesce` function for this problem.

Can you please help?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors to stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2017 or later, the [`CONCAT_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function provides a nice way of doing this:

```sql
SELECT
    Title + CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) AS FullName
FROM employees
WHERE BusinessEntityID IN (1, 2, 4);
```

`CONCAT_WS()` will ignore null parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you have is (naive) concatenation of nulls makes the whole string null. The question of whether to just use `concat`/`concat_ws` or `coalesce`/`isnull` comes down to whether or not you want null values to be interpreted as an empty string, or if you want to substitute a different value in there.

If all you want is an empty string, a variant of `concat` is the simplest way to go. You would typically want/need to reach for `coalesce/isnull` if you wanted to replace the value with something *other than* an empty string (I've given a few examples like if for some reason you want to give everyone a default middle name of `x`. Ridiculous, I know.). That's not to say you *cant* do it that way, it's just easier with `concat`.

Here are a couple different ways you could look at your problem. Please not however, that if your middle name is null, the fact that you're doing `' ' + isnull(Middle, '') + ' '` or you're using `concat` rather than `concat_ws`, that means that if your middle name is null, you're going to have *two* spaces in your string, not one. You'll need to take that into consideration when you handle your nulls.

```
;with a ( first, Middle, last) as
(
    select 'Janos', 'j', 'Sanchez' union all
    select 'Rob', null, 'walters'
)
select
    First,
    Middle,
    Last,
    NaiveConcat = First + ' ' + Middle + ' ' + Last,
    NaiveConcatWithCoalesce = coalesce(First, '') + ' ' + coalesce(Middle, '') + ' ' + coalesce(Last, ''),
    NaiveConcatWithSubstitution = isnull(First, '') + ' ' + isnull(Middle, 'x') + ' ' + isnull(Last, ''),
    NaiveConcatWithIsnull= isnull(First, '') + ' ' + isnull(Middle, '') + ' ' + isnull(Last, ''),
    TrueConcat = concat(First, ' ', Middle, ' ', Last), -- watch out for double spaces!
    TrueConcatWithSubstitution = concat(First, ' ', isnull(Middle, 'x'), ' ', Last),
    WSConcat = concat_ws(' ', First, Middle, Last)
from a
```

Comment: `FirstName + ' ' + isnull(Middle + ' ', '') + LastName` is a common solution